# Drag down a sum formula but change column reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to drag down a sum formula but change the column reference in stead of row reference.

For example cell

```
E1 =sum('Sheet2!C3:C)
E2 =sum('Sheet2!D3:D)
E3 =sum('Sheet2!E3:E)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the formula that use query, C & E can be changed to future actual range:

```
= arrayformula(query(transpose(query(C3:E +0,"select " & join(",","sum(Col" & COLUMN(C3:E3)-Column(C3)+1 & ")") )),"Select Col2"))
```

Comment: Hey this works great! Do you know what I can do if I need every third column? so for example I would need:
E1 =sum('Sheet2!C3:C)
E2 =sum('Sheet2!F3:F)
E3 =sum('Sheet2!I3:I)

Answer (score 2):

For the example you shared, see if this works (in E1)

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(transpose(N(Sheet2!C3:E)), row(C3:C)^0))
```

Change range to suit.
This formula outputs an array, so dragging down is not needed.